# Json Array from PHP MySQL

Tags: php, android, json

I am getting my json response from php file for my android app in this form

```
[{"countryname":"India","flag":"http:\/\/india.in\/india.png"}]
```

and I need it in this form, please suggest me some help.

```
{"countries":[{"countryname":"India","flag":"http:\/\/india.in\/india.png"}]}
```

Comment: How did the first JSON string transform into the second one? Is it just random? Where did the `countries` come from?

Comment: I said I need it in this(second) form

Comment: Can't you alter the PHP?

Comment: @Nfear Sorry, but I am new in php so can you plz tell me with this code

  $sql=mysql_query("select * from t1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

  $output[]=$row;  
    
  json_encode($output);
  print(json_encode($output));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your array in php, which you encode into json. Now you need to add another array-level around like this:

```
$country = array('countryname' -> 'India', ...);
$countries = array('countries' => $country );
echo json_encode($countries);
```

This is just my guess, because you didn't show any code.

**Update**

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from t1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $output[]=$row;
}
// json_encode($output); doesn't do anything useful

$countries = array('countries' => $output);

echo json_encode($countries);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am new in php so can you plz tell me with this code

    $sql=mysql_query("select * from t1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

    $output[]=$row;  
    
    json_encode($output);
    print(json_encode($output));

Comment: thank you so much...you made my app work...plz do let me know if I can help you with something.